# Ordenar listas en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Necesito retornar la lista `facturas` ordenada por el campo `entidades`.

Lo he intentado asi pero no me funciona:

```
facturas.OrderBy(f => f.Entidades).ToList();
```

**Código:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var facturas = db.Facturas
        .Include( f => f.Entidades )
        .Include( f => f.Estados )
        .Include( f => f.FormasPagos )
        .Include( f => f.Numeraciones );


    return View( facturas.ToList( ));
}
```

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida. No hace falta q hagas la pregunta en inglés

Comment: Que no te funciona en lo que has probado? Te da error de compilación? Resultado no esperado? Danos algo mas de información

Comment: y que es lo que no funciona???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuyo que el problema es que esperas que la colección se ordene en `facturas`. `OrderBy` asi como otros métodos de LINQ devuelven una nueva colección, no actuan sobre la colección original. Prueba con:

```
var facturasOrdenadas=facturas.OrderBy(f => f.Entidades.Nombre).ToList();
```

Y usa `facturasOrdenadas` si quieres manejar la coleccón ordenada.

Comment: Hola tambien la habia progbado asi pero me genera un error: **                   Error: DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.**

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon esa información. El error parece claro, de que tipo es tu propiedad `Entidades`? si no es un tipo básico, debes implementar la interfaz `IComparable` para que se sepa como se ordenan los elementos

Comment: Gracias, Me faltaba especificarle por cual campo de entidades.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres actualizarla sobre la misma tienes que utilizar Sort

```
facturas.Sort(f => f.Entidades).ToList();
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188141/list-orderby-alphabetical-order

Answer (score 1):

en teoría OrderBy se le puede asiganar a todo lo que retorne una colección, por lo que sí se le puede poner al final de la colección facturas. el tema está en el parámetro por el que esta ordenando pues Entidades no representa un atributo de la clase factura sino una tabla que debe tener sus atributos propios. En resúmen que la consulta puede quedar de esta manera:

```
 var facturas = db.Facturas
    .Include( f => f.Entidades )
    .Include( f => f.Estados )
    .Include( f => f.FormasPagos )
    .Include( f => f.Numeraciones ).OrderBy(f => f.Entidades.Nombre);
```